# es6 object literal syntax for Python?

Tags: python, ecmascript-6

In ES6 javascript,

```
obj = {
  foo
}
```

In python

```
obj = {
  'foo': foo
}
```

I find ES6 syntax really convenient, is there a way to achieve similar syntax in python?

edit:

I just want to type `foo` once, it doesn't have to be `{foo}`

Something like, (not sure it's robust)

```
def es_dict(names): 

   return {
      name: eval(name) for name in names
   }

es_dict(["foo"]) == {"foo": foo}
```

Comment: Unlikely; `{ foo }` is a valid set literal in Python.

Comment: yeah, just want to type `foo` once. it doesn't have to be `{ foo}`